# Unwanted popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a older iOS app that I am working on a update for.  Compiling with 8.2 and 8.3 SDK I get unwanted pops to the root view controller, running on 8.3 or 7.1 iOS.  Depending on the specific view configuration when I add the 2nd view to the stack I will get a instant, after viewDidAppear, pop to the rootViewController from the 2nd view or 3rd view on the stack.  I have breakpointed all my popTo statements and non of them are causing it.  I am getting no indication of the cause.  Are there any debug tools that can help me find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass the navigation controller and override the popToRootViewController method with an implementation that just calls super. Put a breakpoint in there and you should be able to pinpoint the cause. (Make sure you replace the default navigation controller with the subclass).

If popToRootViewController still does not get called, the other view controllers might be getting deallocated or dismissed for some reason.

Comment: Perfect, already had it subclassed for something else.  Added pop method  and found it in 10 sec.  Thanks,

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was it?

Comment: I had some old code in the app delegate that I thought I had disabled to popToRootViewController when a notification fired based on a settings change.  Looking at it now I see why it was happening but what is weird is that this block of code did not come up when I performed a search for all popToRootViewController statements.  Will have to look into that.